# Is it possible to create an Office365 account that sends emails on other people's behalf?

Tags: email, email-server, microsoft-office-365

I have an internal app that needs to send emails on other people's behalf.  For instance, I might need to send an email from a@company.com, b@company.com and c@company.com to target@company.com.

All our email is in Office365.  Basically, this is relaying email and it does sound close to what spammers do.

Is this possible to with Office365?  What permissions would the account need to have?

Answer (score 1):

a lot has to do with how you are achieving this.
Using an "App", you would usually create a service account for this purpose, create a new role for this account and grant impersonation rights to the role.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/661640/send-email-from-server-without-creating-new-office-365-user-account-mailbox/661646#661646) The [last answer](https://serverfault.com/a/661654/415490) references [this technet guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx) that can walk you through the setup. We have accomplished this by adding a SMTP relay (mail flow connector) that validates our ip address.

Comment: Currently we are facing an issue when the sender domain is not an Authoritative domain within Exchange Online. It prevents the sender from  emailing recipients in multiple domains. Otherwise it should work for the use case specified.